# Running Heroku Spring MVC App locally

Tags: spring, spring-mvc, heroku

## Spring Newbie

Hi guys, I was trying out heroku to develop a Spring MVC application. I used its 'Spring MVC and Tomcat Application' template to create a Spring App. Is there a way I can deploy it on my local tomcat server for testing ?

After I created a project, with the default configuration, I was not able to see the 'Run On Server' when I tried to run my project. I was not able to see the project in the 'available resources' section of the server too.

I followed [this](http://java.dzone.com/articles/spring-heroku) blog to create a self contained web application, but it started thorwing these errors after I run its Main :

```
Problem accessing /. Reason:

    No org.apache.tomcat.InstanceManager set in ServletContext
```

Isnt there an easier method to run the app locally, without running it as a self hosted web application ? (Not even sure if it was the right thing to do to run it locally.)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This did it :

$mvn clean install
Then run it with:

$java -jar target/dependency/webapp-runner.jar target/*.war